# QTP: How do I match (or parametrize) line breaks in multiline edit controls?

Tags: regex, testing, qtp

Consider this script:

```
SystemUtil.Run "notepad.exe"
With Window("Notepad")
    .WinEditor("Edit").Type "A"
    .WinEditor("Edit").Type  micReturn
    .WinEditor("Edit").Type "B"
  .WinEditor("Edit").Check CheckPoint("Edit")
End With
```

The "Edit" checkpoint simply checks if the "Edit" WinEdit contains "A", CR, LF, "B". (This is exactly what the editor contains, you can verify by looking at `GetROProperty ("Text")`, it returns a string of length 4 with ASCII 65, 13, 10, 66, which is exactly what I'd expect.) I can easily create such a checkpoint after recording the script and inserting the checkpoint via active screen click-o-magic.

**But now suppose I want to parametrize the expected string. 
Since I cannot enter line breaks in a data table cell, I would convert the expected string to a regular expression, for example `"A\cM\cJB"` for above example. No matter if I put that regex into a data table or not, it does not match. Why?**

Or is there any other way to parametrize an expected string containing a line break?

Also see Question [QTP: How do I get the "complex value" edit control in the checkpoint property edit dialog?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5554229/397667).

Comment: Support told me they don't know why it does not work. They say regexes seem not to work in this context. I disagreed, cause they work, just the newline stuff does not work, so i wait for updates again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Facts:

1. Newline characters in the
   checkpoint's expected value are *not
   supported*.  While this seems
   obvious, in fact all regex tokens
   for newline, including `\cM` and `\cJ`,
   are not handled in the expected way.
2. It does not matter if the value is
   in the datatable (being a datatable
   parameter for the checkpoint) or
   inserted into the checkpoint
   directly.
3. Support says this is because the third-party Formula1 component used to implement the data table editor in QTP cannot use newline characters.
4. (3) cannot be true because then (2) would not be true.
5. Support suggests to put a formula into the data table which delivers the wanted string, for example '`="A"+Chr(13)+Chr(10)+Chr("B")`'.

   I think that is quite delighting.

So once again, i answered my own question, but not to earn the respect points (will I earn any?), but to share the "solution", or workaround, with everybody.

The QTP version used was 10.00.